# make an element sized/behave like background-size: contain

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make an element behave/sized like the `background-size:contain`?  For reference, [here's a page](http://whereswalden.com/files/mozilla/background-size/page-contain.html) demonstrating `background-size:contain` (try resizing your browser window and see what the background image does).

That is, I want to make an element with constrained aspect ratio, with width and height such that either width or height will be 100% of the window width (and the other will be whatever is necessary to preserve ratio and keep the entire element visible in the window without scrollbars)?

For example, suppose I want an element to have a ratio of 16:9. If someone's browser window is super wide and not very tall, then I want my element's height to be 100% and the width would be less (whatever is necessary to keep the element's ratio 16:9). If someone's browser window is really tall and not very wide, then the width would be be 100% and the height would be less (again, whatever is necessary to preserve that element's target ratio).

I'm thinking the only way to do this is with javascript. Is there some magical CSS way to accomplish this that I don't know about?

Comment: So, to clarify, you're looking to style an element to it stays in the same ratio (say, 16:9), but scales so one length is 100%?

Comment: God it's late. Looks like I said "cover" when I meant "contain". But yes, you have the right idea. I want one length to be 100%, and the other length to be whatever is necessary to preserve ratio and keep the whole element in the window. Let me update my question.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want to have a liquid template view.

Checkout this example if it suits your need

http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/liquid-sample1/

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but if you resize your browser window while viewing that layout, you'll see the boxes all change ratios (of width to height) as you resize.